# Strange problem with find command on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

I used the 'find' command to find a file and encountered a strange issue:
**the file exists, but 'find' can't find it**

I found two .sock in /run with **'sudo find /run -name docker.sock'**

```
$sudo find /run -name docker.sock
/run/march/docker.sock
/run/docker.sock
```

I got nothing when run **'sudo find /var -name docker.sock'** and **'sudo find /var/run -name docker.sock'**

```
$sudo find /var -name docker.sock
$sudo find /var/run -name docker.sock
$
```

**but in fact there are two .sock in /var/run/**, any comments?

```
$ls -al /var/run/docker.sock
srwxrwxrwx+ 1 root docker 0 Oct 18 20:45 /var/run/docker.sock
$ls -al /var/run/march/docker.sock/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  40 Oct 31 20:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 100 Oct 31 20:35 ..
$ls -al /var/run/march/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  100 Oct 31 20:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 34 root root 1120 Oct 31 23:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Oct 31 20:35 docker
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Oct 31 20:35 docker.pid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Oct 31 20:35 docker.sock
$
$
```

BTW it's on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: `/var/run` `!=` `/run/`

Comment: @tink I don’t know that /var/run is a symbolic link to /run, so I didn't understand your comment, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As /var/run is a symbolic link to /run, you have to tell `find` to follow links :

```
sudo find -L /var/run -name docker.sock
```